# iText doesn't add table with one row

Tags: java, spring, itext

I'm creating a PDF document with a number of tables and when the table has only one row it doesn't add it to the document. I checked that the row is completed as I saw this in another post, and added the `table.completeRow()` just in case. However the only way it works is adding another empty row:

```
table.addCell(new Paragraph("", paragraphFontNormal));
table.completeRow()
```

I don't think this is a nice solution and I'd like to know what's wrong here. Can anyone help please?

This is the method:

```
public void createPdf(DateRange dates, HttpServletResponse response) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    boolean first = true;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
    document.open();

    List<Rejects> report = findAll(dates);

    for(Rejects rejects : report){
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            addGroupAdmin(rejects, document, dates);
        }else{
            if (rejects.getAdminGroup().equals(adminGroup)) {
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getZone(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(dateFormat.format(rejects.getRejDate()), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getProcName(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getKindId(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getVarietyName(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getSlrn(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getRejReason(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getAdminGroup(), paragraphFontNormal));
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getDescription(), paragraphFontNormal));
            }else{

                /*** It doesn't work like this for one row***/  
                document.add(table);

                document.newPage();
                addGroupAdmin(rejects, document, dates);
            }
        }
    }

    /*** It works like this ***/
    table.addCell(new Paragraph("", paragraphFontNormal));
    table.completeRow();
    document.add(table);

    document.newPage();
    response.flushBuffer();
    document.close();
}
```

This is the addGroupAdmin method:

```
private void addGroupAdmin(Rejects rejects, Document document, DateRange dates) throws DocumentException {
        adminGroup = rejects.getAdminGroup();
        Paragraph headLine = new Paragraph("REJECTED APPLICATION LIST " + dateFormat.format(dates.getStartDate())
                + "-" + dateFormat.format(dates.getEndDate()) + " - " + rejects.getAdminGroupDesc() , paragraphFontBold);
        headLine.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(headLine);
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

        table = new PdfPTable(9);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.getDefaultCell().setMinimumHeight(20);
        table.getDefaultCell().setPaddingBottom(10);
        table.setWidthPercentage(900);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);
        table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{ 40, 60, 140, 30, 60, 90, 30, 90, 100 });
        table.setLockedWidth(true);

        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getZone(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(dateFormat.format(rejects.getRejDate()), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getProcName(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getKindId(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getVarietyName(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getSlrn(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getRejReason(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getAdminGroup(), paragraphFontNormal));
        table.addCell(new Paragraph(rejects.getDescription(), paragraphFontNormal));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set

```
table.setHeaderRows(1);
```

This means that the first row you add to the table is used as header row.

Thus, if

> the table has only one row

then the table has a header row but no content rows. iText ignores tables without content rows. Thus,

> it doesn't add it to the document.

So the solution is **not to set `HeaderRows`** in your `addGroupAdmin` method!

Comment: Thanks @mkl !! I use tables with heading in a different report. That's the problem when you copy and paste :) Such as silly thing, cheers!